# WooCommerce: verify coupon user email manually

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a coupon code called "SIGNUP10" that has to be made available to only users that have their email address in our mailchimp list. I know the coupon can be restricted to certain email addresses under "allowed emails" but I have a big mailchimp list and I need to make sure that the user applying this coupon has their email in our list.

Is there a woocoomerce hook that lets me check the email address after the coupon is entered and before the coupon is verified and applied to the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this hook:

> woocommerce_applied_coupon

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_applied_coupon', 'restrict_coupon_usage_with_my_email_list' );
function restrict_coupon_usage_with_my_email_list( $coupon_code )
{
    //create an array with your email list
    $emailArr = array("a@a.com", "b@b.com");
    $isSpecialCoupon = false;

    //check the $coupon_code 
    if($coupon_code == "a_b_coupon" && is_user_logged_in())
    {
       //if it is the coupon code you want to restrict with those emails and if user logged in
       $isSpecialCoupon = true;
    }
    if($isSpecialCoupon)
    {
       //check if the logged in user's email is in this array
       $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
       if(in_array($current_user->user_email, $emailArr)) return true;
       else WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
    }
    else WC()->cart->remove_coupon( $coupon_code );
}
```

Tested and works fine (except the coupon message which also can be edited), but I hope that may help you.

Btw: I believe using regular "allowed emails" feature is better for speed&performance.

Extra: You may also check this free plugin to restrict WooCommerce coupons: https://wordpress.org/plugins/global-coupons-for-woocommerce/